# Is there anything I can do to warn others about a bad company?

Tags: bullying

I was very successful in my position until I started to be bullied. I was criticised in an offensive, not constructive way. Rumours were spread about me. I was portrayed in an extremely negative light to people I had never met who treated me like a monster during our first meeting. People with whom I used to have very good contacts suddenly started to avoid me.

It cost me plenty of energy and health. I discussed it with several therapists and all described the situation as a clear "bulling".

It's a big company and it has a bad reputation on glassdoor compared to other companies in the same industry and region. A few people described experiences similar to mine. (I was stupid enough not to consult glassdoor before accepting the position).

Is there anything else I can do to warn others against the company apart from writing an online review?

Comment: Name and shame them on /r/cscareerquestions.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there anything else I can do to warn others against the company
>   apart from writing an online review?

Yes.

Anytime a friend asks you for your opinion about the company, you can give your honest opinion and explain what happened to you.